# Is there a simple way to explain making an ArrayList of objects or is there a problem with Ready to Program?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

So I am trying to create an array list of objects for a class project an I've looked around the internet for answers to this question but I don't really understand what is incorrect in my code. I am new to coding so it is probably something really simple (it is probably Ready to program seeing as it is very **not normal** to put it lightly)! So I am trying to create an ArrayList of the object subscribers and whenever I try to create a normal ArrayList with `ArrayList sub = new ArrayList();` Ready to program is fine but when I do `ArrayList<subscriber> arraylist = new ArrayList<subscriber>();`  it highlights both the `<` saying `( expected instead of this token` and on the `(` it says `Invalid ShiftExpression`. I have no idea how to fix these errors, also this is the whole code that could be affected by this:

```
static boolean done = false;
ArrayList<subscriber> arraylist = new ArrayList<subscriber>();
```

On line 2 of the pasted code (`static boolean done = false;`), there is another error caused by the object array. Due to this error the semicolon is highlighted with the syntax error of `[ expected instead of this token`. I am extremely confused with this last one and would like to know if this problem is to do with my code or with Ready to Program (probably my code). And before people ask, no I am not using HSA and I'm trying to learn proper java (I've seen lots of people hating on the buggy mess that is HSA and I am trying to move away from it.

Edit: It turns out it is a bug with Ready to Program. Sorry for wasting your guys' time!

Comment: Is the soruce level at least 1.5?

Comment: Honestly, it's hard to follow what you are asking. Please show a [mcve] rather than trying to describe the problem in words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a bug in Ready to Program and not in Java. I tried the exact same code in Visual Studio Code and it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you would have to have another class called subscriber. You can't just make up a word and put it in the angle brackets of the ArrayList. For example

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()
```

Integer is not a made up word, it is an internal class object that that is used by the arraylist.

As for your second error i suspect you are not doing this code inside a method, and intstead just doing it outside of the class.

Overall tho it is very hard to see what you are doing via your description and two lines of code you have posted.